# Joint Distribution of a Possion Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

> Let $X\sim Poisson(m)$ and $m\sim\Gamma(2,1)$ then the join probability distribution function of $X$ and $m$ is given by $$\begin{align}f(x,m)&=f(x\mid x)\;f(m)\\&=\frac{m^xe^{-m}}{x!}\cdot\frac1{\Gamma(2)}me^{-m}\\&=\frac{m^{x+1}e^{-2m}}{x!}\end{align}$$

I understand how to find $f(m)$. Yet I have no idea how they got $f(x\mid m)$. Would someone be kind enough to show me the steps needed in order to arrive at that answer for $f(x\mid m)$?

Comment: Do you know what the Poisson distribution is? That is the probability mass function for the Poisson(m) distribution.

Comment: I understand the rudiments of poisson distribution I believe. Ok, so the Conditional Distribution function of a poisson distribution will always just be the PMF?

Comment: When you are conditioning on the value of the Poisson **parameter**, as in this case, the answer is yes. However, it is a very different story to find, say the conditional pmf for a Poisson random variable $X$ given that it is even or given the value of another random variable $Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ have some known joint distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The notation used here is obnoxious, using the same letter for different things.  We have a function $m\mapsto f(m)$ and you're supposed to understand which function $f$ is by noticing that you're calling its argument $m$ rather than $x$.  So if $m=3$, then you have $f(3)$.  Does that mean "$f(m=3)$" or "$f(x=3)$"?  When one writes $f_X(x)$, using capital $X$ as the random variable and $x$ as the argument to the function, then $f_X(3)$ is comprehensible and so is $\Pr(X\le x)$.

I'll use capital $M$ for the continuous random variable in this case and lower-case $m$ for the argument to its density function.  Then $f_M(m) = me^{-m}$ for $m>0$, and $f_{X\,\mid\,M}(x) = \dfrac{m^x e^{-m}}{x!}$.

They ought to have said $X\mid M\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(M)$ rather than $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(M)$.  The latter would mean the marginal distribution of $X$ is a Poisson distribution, and that is not true.

The thing that was written in obnoxious notation as $f(x\mid m)= \dfrac{m^xe^{-m}}{x!}$ should have been written as $f_{X\,\mid\,M}(x) = \dfrac{M^xe^{-M}}{x!}$ or as $f_{X\,\mid\, M=m}(x) = \dfrac{m^xe^{-m}}{x!}$.

As to where they got it: it was given that $X\mid M\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(M)$, and you know that the probability mass function for the Poisson distribution with expected value $M$ is $x\mapsto \dfrac{M^x e^{-M}}{x!}$.

Furthermore, the phrase "probability distribution function" is misleading, since that is often taken to mean the cumulative distribution function, and that is clearly not what is meant here.